# Python Flask: How do I get around 'ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]'?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been developing a little forum site with a basic login system. My Flask app functions as it should when logging in, however whenever I use 'return redirect(url_for("index"))' I seem to get an exception problem in my Flask which stops the app. The error it produces is:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MY DIRECTORY\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "MY DIRECTORY\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "MY DIRECTORY\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "MY DIRECTORY\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "MY DIRECTORY\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "MY DIRECTORY\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "MY FLASK APP FILE\app.py", line 16, in index
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
  File "MY FLASK APP FILE\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1022, in cursor
    self.handle_unread_result()
  File "MY FLASK APP FILE\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1286, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

How can I prevent this from happening, I assume I need to do something with a GET but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are using mysql connector. To fix this,change the properties of the cursor object.

```
cursor = <connection-name>.cursor(buffered=True)
```

This must solve your issue.